# Promote certain rows to index in an ordered pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(index=['Asia','China','India','Europe','France','Hungary'])
df[2008]=20080
df[2009]=20090
df.loc['Europe']=np.NaN
df.loc['Asia']=np.NaN
print df

          2008   2009
Asia       NaN    NaN
China    20080  20090
India    20080  20090
Europe     NaN    NaN
France   20080  20090
Hungary  20080  20090
```

I would like to "promote" Europe and Asia to be MultiIndexes, one level higher than their component countries to yield:

```
                  2008   2009
Asia    China    20080  20090
        India    20080  20090
Europe  France   20080  20090
        Hungary  20080  20090
```

Is that possible in a pretty way, knowing that these promotable rows have all NaNs?

Comment: Also, the dataframe is ordered, so in theory, between the all-NaN lines of Asia and Europe, let's say there are only Asian countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `cumsum()`:

```
In [11]: cont = df.isnull().all(1)

In [12]: cont
Out[12]:
Asia        True
China      False
India      False
Europe      True
France     False
Hungary    False
dtype: bool
```

This enables you to label the continents for each row*:

```
In [13]: continents = df.index[cont][cont.cumsum() - 1]

In [14]: continents
Out[14]: Index([u'Asia', u'Asia', u'Asia', u'Europe', u'Europe', u'Europe'], dtype='object')

In [15]: df.set_index([continents, df.index], inplace=True)

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
                 2008   2009
Asia   Asia       NaN    NaN
       China    20080  20090
       India    20080  20090
Europe Europe     NaN    NaN
       France   20080  20090
       Hungary  20080  20090

In [17]: df.dropna()
Out[17]:
                 2008   2009
Asia   China    20080  20090
       India    20080  20090
Europe France   20080  20090
       Hungary  20080  20090
```

---

* Note: it can be more efficient to not do this step and set the levels in a MultiIndex:

```
In [21]: res = df.set_index([cont, df.index])

In [21]: res.index = res.index.set_levels(df.index[cont], 0)
```

Furthermore, you could construct this *without* the NaN (so you don't have to dropna afterwards).

---

*Note: it may be a more efficient to do this while reading in as your data (i.e. during construction/concat)...*

Comment: `cumsum` is awesome!. I brute-forced it before like: for i in df.T.iteritems(): if np.isnan(i[1]).all(): superIndex.append(currentIndex)